# org.grails.datastore.mapping.collection.PersistentSet not serializable?

Tags: mongodb, grails

In our Grails application storing the User object to session we get this:

java.io.NotSerializableException: org.grails.datastore.mapping.collection.PersistentSet

This just logging / testing I added to find out, what is causing the issue. So it must some of the User object's association to other objects. How to find out, which object it actually is? All of our domain classes implement Serializable interface. Grails version is 2.4.4 and MongoDB plugin version is 3.0.2

Answer (score 1):

Please file an issue for this, looks like https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/blob/master/grails-datastore-core/src/main/groovy/org/grails/datastore/mapping/collection/PersistentSet.java needs to be made serialisable